# Distinguish function vs closure

Tags: lua

Lua will write the code of a function out as bytes using string.dump, but warns that this does not work if there are any upvalues. Various snippets online describe hacking around this with debug. It looks like 'closed over variables' are called 'upvalues', which seems clear enough. Code is not data etc.

I'd like to serialise functions and don't need them to have any upvalues. The serialised function can take a table as an argument that gets serialised separately.

How do I detect attempts to pass closures to string.dump, before calling the broken result later?

Current thought is debug.getupvalue at index 1 and treat nil as meaning function, as opposed to closure, but I'd rather not call into the debug interface if there's an alternative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Even with debug library it's very difficult to say whether a function has a non-trivial upvalue.
"Non-trivial" means "upvalue except _ENV".
When debug info is stripped from your program, all upvalues look almost the same :-)

```
local function test()

    local function f1()
        -- usual function without upvalues (except _ENV for accessing globals)
        print("Hello")
    end

    local upv = {}
    local function f2()
        -- this function does have an upvalue
        upv[#upv+1] = ""
    end

    -- display first upvalues
    print(debug.getupvalue (f1, 1))
    print(debug.getupvalue (f2, 1))
end

test()

local test_stripped = load(string.dump(test, true))
test_stripped()
```

Output:

```
_ENV       table: 00000242bf521a80   -- test f1
upv        table: 00000242bf529490   -- test f2
(no name)  table: 00000242bf521a80   -- test_stripped f1
(no name)  table: 00000242bf528e90   -- test_stripped f2
```

The first two lines of the output are printed by `test()`, the last two lines by `test_stripped()`.
As you see, inside `test_stripped` functions `f1` and `f2` are almost undistinguishable.

Comment: That's interesting. Does _ENV get special treatment? a `local function f3() return "hello" end` returns nil for getupvalue, with debug info stripped or not, so via debug interface still looks workable.

Comment: `Does _ENV get special treatment?` - It is included if a function accesses global variables.  `f3` does not, so it has 0 upvalues.